# Azure timertriggered webjob hangs randomly

Tags: c#, azure, scheduled-tasks, azure-webjobs

I want to schedule a timertriggered method to call other methods but somehow the CronJob method won't run if I use it to call one of my own methods, I simply get this console output:
"
Found the following functions: 
...ProcessQueueMessage 
...Functions.CronJob 
Job host started
"

and nothing else happens for a couple of minutes and then it might suddenly start working. But if I only use the CronJob() method for running it's own Console.WriteLine("Timer job fired") statement everything works.

I have been trying to find a solution to this problem for hours now but no one seems to have the same problem. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

```
public static void CronJob([TimerTrigger("*/3 * * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timerInfo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Timer job fired! ");
        DoTask();

    }

    private static void DoTask()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Doing task...");
    }
```

Main method:

```
static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        var host = new JobHost(config);
        config.UseTimers();
        // The following code ensures that the WebJob will be running continuously
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your  static void Main() function in Program.cs?

Comment: Yes, added it to the main post

Comment: Are you seeing these problems when running locally, on an Azure Web App instance, or both?

Comment: At least when running locally it happens all the time. EDIT: it happens on both

Comment: Can you set the JobHostConfiguration.Tracing.ConsoleLevel to Verbose  and see if this sheds light on things? I'm wondering if you're not experiencing an issue with the TimerTrigger singleton lock.

Comment: While we are at the topic is it common practice to call other methods from a TimeTrigger method?

Comment: Absolutely, other methods are often called from a TimerTrigger method.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the possible singleton lock issue? This problem is really getting on my nerves now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

According to your description, it is **not related with** whether you call code directly. The root reason is that a blob lease (the Singleton Lock) is taken for a default time of **30** seconds.

As Rob Reagan mention that you could set JobHostConfiguration.Tracing.ConsoleLeve
to Verbose. When the webjob hangs you could get the information **"Unable to aquire Singleton lock"**.

For more detail info you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/issues/25).

> When the listener starts for a particular TimerTrigger function, a blob lease (the Singleton Lock) is taken for a default time of 30 seconds. This is the lock that ensures that only a single instance of your scheduled function is running at any time. **If you kill your console app, that lease will still be held until it expires naturally**

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, that link was also really useful!